# Learning Assembly num function

Tags: assembly, x86, att

So I'm learning Assembly and i have come across this code:

`movl num(,%eax,4), %eax`

Can someone explain what that num() function is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a function, it is an element of the AT&T assembly syntax. That line means "move 32-bit value at address `eax*4 + num` to `eax`".

In Intel syntax it would be `mov eax, [eax*4 + num]`.

Comment: Oh wow i didnt realize this was the AT&T assembly syntax. The more you know!